# How a platform specific subscribes to an event in a PCL ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross + PCL and need to fire an event on my ViewModel in this PCL. I need the plafotm specific iOS ViewController to listem to this event.

How can I accoumplish that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

Why not just create a regular C# event?

In your ViewModel:

```
public event EventHandler Something;
```

In your View/ViewController/Page:

```
ViewModel.Something += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Something!");
```